# Adding an ArrayOfEnum column to table with alembic

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, alembic

I have defined an 'ArrayOfEnum' type as described here: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/postgresql.html

The upgrade function in my version file contains the following code:

```
op.add_column('example_table_name', sa.Column('example_column_name', ArrayOfEnum(postgresql.ENUM('ENUM_VALUE_1', 'ENUM_VALUE_2', name='ExampleEnumName')), nullable=True))
```

Attempting to execute the migration gives the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) type "ExampleEnumName[]" does not exist
```

Any solution to this? Did I misuse the ArrayOfEnum type?